# Is it possible to exclude some members of a type from XmlSerializer serialization?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, ixmlserializable

I have some public members I don't want to be serialized, was wondering if there is an attribute for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for [XmlIgnore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Use **XmlIgnoreAttribute** to do it statically, as others advised you.

You can also do it dynamically. Suppose you have a serializable property **Name**.  Then the following:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public bool NameSpecified {
    get {
        // your logic here
    }
}
```

If this special property getter returns true, **Name** will be included in the output XML document, otherwise, it won't be included.  **NameSpecified** itself is marked with [XmlIgnore] because you obviously don't want to include it.

Answer (score 4):

[`XmlIgnore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlignore.aspx) will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Use XmlIgnore attribute

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Azheglov's comment regarding the "Specified" suffix, the `DefaultValue` attribute is also considered when serializing, and a value won't be serialized at all if it is the default.